# How to split array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have super placeholder with animation and I want to get placeholder text from my `data-other-placeholder` attribute

my related area is here

```
$(function() {

        var placeTarget       = $(".search-hotels"),
            dataValue         = placeTarget.attr("placeholder"),
            getPlaceholder    = placeTarget.data("other-placeholder"),
            placeholderText   = [getPlaceholder],
            targetText = [dataValue];
        if ((dataValue == "") || (dataValue == undefined)) {
            placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
                text: placeholderText,
                delay: 70,
                loop: false,
            });
        } else {
            placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
                text: targetText,
                delay: 70,
                loop: false,
            });
        }

    });
```

as you se I have data-other-placeholder and I want to split with  `|` how to do that ?

my complete code

```js
/*
 jQuery placeholderTypewriter plugin
 ===================================
 Author: Bjoern Diekert <https://github.com/bdiekert>
 Version: 1.1.0
 License: Unlicense <http://unlicense.org>
 */
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $.fn.placeholderTypewriter = function(options) {

    // Plugin Settings
    var settings = $.extend({
      delay: 50,
      pause: 1000,
      text: [],
      loop: true
    }, options);

    // Type given string in placeholder
    function typeString($target, index, cursorPosition, callback) {

      // Get text
      var text = settings.text[index];

      // Get placeholder, type next character
      var placeholder = $target.attr('placeholder');
      $target.attr('placeholder', placeholder + text[cursorPosition]);

      // Type next character
      if (cursorPosition < text.length - 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeString($target, index, cursorPosition + 1, callback);
        }, settings.delay);
        return true;
      }

      // Callback if animation is finished
      callback();
    }

    // Delete string in placeholder
    function deleteString($target, callback) {

      // Get placeholder
      var placeholder = $target.attr('placeholder');
      var length = placeholder.length;

      // Delete last character
      $target.attr('placeholder', placeholder.substr(0, length - 1));

      // Delete next character
      if (length > 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          deleteString($target, callback)
        }, settings.delay);
        return true;
      }

      // Callback if animation is finished
      callback();
    }

    // Loop typing animation
    function loopTyping($target, index) {

      // Clear Placeholder
      $target.attr('placeholder', '');

      // Type string
      typeString($target, index, 0, function() {

        // Up index
        index = index + 1;

        // If loop is false, just run through the array once
        if (index === settings.text.length && !settings.loop) {
          return false;
        }

        // Pause before deleting string
        setTimeout(function() {

          // Delete string
          deleteString($target, function() {
            // Start loop over
            loopTyping($target, index % settings.text.length)
          })

        }, settings.pause);
      })

    }

    // Run placeholderTypewriter on every given field
    return this.each(function() {

      loopTyping($(this), 0);
    });

  };

}(jQuery));

$(function() {

  var placeTarget = $(".search-hotels"),
    dataValue = placeTarget.attr("placeholder"),
    getPlaceholder = placeTarget.data("other-placeholder");
  placeholderText = [getPlaceholder],
    targetText = [dataValue];
  if ((dataValue == "") || (dataValue == undefined)) {
    placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
      text: placeholderText,
      delay: 70,
      loop: false,
    });
  } else {
    placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
      text: targetText,
      delay: 70,
      loop: false,
    });
  }

});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-hotels" placeholder="" data-other-placeholder="Test 1| Test 2| Test3" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this is

```
var placeholderText = [
    "Where would you like to go?",
    "Amsterdam?", 
    "Paris?", 
    "Berlin?", 
    "London?", 
    "New York?", 
    "San Francisco?"
  ];
```

placeholder area and I want to get this placeholder text from `data-other-placeholder` and I want to split then with `|` so placeholder animation start one by one

Comment: Is there a reason you are making a single data field contain multiple values, instead of having multiple data fields?

Comment: `placeTarget.data("otherPlaceholder").split("|")` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect to see once the string is split

Comment: I want to split my text with `|` https://github.com/bdiekert/jquery-placeholder-typewriter to get like this result I have dynamic variables

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You simply split the string using the [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) command as seen below.

That will give you an array of strings.

```
var bits = placeTarget.data("other-placeholder").split("|")
```

Comment: thanks, so what do I have to do to see item ? how can I loop result ?

Comment: @ani_css  You don't need to.   `placeholderTypewriter` already does all that looping for you.

Comment: That would be a new questions to be honest, your question was how to split the value which is what I have answered. After I would suggest writing a new post with your new issue and detailing exactly how it should work which you failed to do here. One thing to make clear which isn't right now is how you want the text used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method of strings.

So

```
placeholderText   = [getPlaceholder],
targetText = [dataValue]
```

should become

```
placeholderText   = (getPlaceholder || '').split('|'),
targetText = (dataValue || '').split('|')
```

(*the `|| ''` is to handle `undefined`*)